# issue with php and Json

Tags: php, json

i cant for the life of me figure out why i cant get this JSON to work

this is how it comes back from api

```
"{"errorCode":5,"errorDescription":"Unknown account"}"
```

i have tried all of the following to get "Unknown account"

```
$error = $result['errorCode":5,"errorDescription'];
$error = $result['errorCode'];
$error = $result['errorDescription'];
```

i would be ok even just trying for error code 5, so i can do a check to further the script if account is made or not.

any ideas what i am missing?

Comment: Show us the code where you fetch the response. Chances are you first have to `json_decode` it, and it's probably `$result->errorCode` after that. Use `print_r` to examine its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$json = '{"errorCode":5,"errorDescription":"Unknown account"}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$error = $arr['errorDescription'];
```

In this case you take the json and parse it into the function `json_decode` of php, wit true value as second parameter It return an associative error where you can get your value by key.

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09b6a00924e5b44266af5e2d927731a22ca708cc)

Comment: omg i had forgotten this  "$result = json_decode($cexecute,true);"

Comment: It can be happen, glad to help you!
Accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem if this has solved your. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a simple matter as there are already builtin functions in PHP for handling JSON. Those are json_encode and json_decode.

```
$result='{"errorCode":5,"errorDescription":"Unknown account"}';
var_dump($result);

$json=json_decode($result);
var_dump($json);

echo "errorCode={$json->errorCode}<br>";
echo "errorDescription={$json->errorDescription}<br>";
```

Try the above. Note that json_decode can convert a string into either an object (default) or an associative array.

```
$json2=json_decode($result,TRUE);
var_dump($json2);

echo "errorCode=".$json2['errorCode']."<br>";
echo "errorDescription=".$json2['errorDescription']."<br>";
```